# Penalize predictions with larger prediction interval

Tags: prediction, prediction-interval

Suppose I am building a model for regression problems. I am quite curious about the following questions:

1. Are there relevant theories that can confirm/disprove the following intuition: we should penalize a point prediction that has larger prediction interval(relative to other points), assuming we can get some kind of measure for the prediction interval (whether the model is linear regression or random forest).
2. If so, what kind of penalization is appropriate? For example, shrinking towards sample mean? Or shrinking towards a constant like 0 under the appropriate context? Other methods?

I tried googling a bit but didn't find much. Maybe it all depends. Any relevant information is appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: An example would be that, given an already trained random forest and a new input X1 and its prediction interval is very small, so it's a sign of high model confidence, so I am happy to use the model estimate; while for another input X2, the prediction interval is large (every tree is giving wildly different predictions), so maybe I should just shrink it towards say, sample mean, and perhaps ultimately it's a better prediction.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that those predictors with limited predictive power in the model will also be those with large confidence intervals (which follows logically), some form of penalised regression is what you are looking for.

In penalised regression, coefficients that add little predictive value are shrunk to zero. The most common penalised regressions are lasso and ridge regression, on which there is a lot of literature available..

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the goal is to penalize predictions (greater loss function) where the model is saying something like, "I'm predicting 5, but I really have no idea," rather than anything to do with standard errors of regression parameters.

Comment: Ah right, I see. Well in that case I must say I don't really understand how you would want to penalise - the model gives the most logical estimate given the data.. If it really has no idea based on regressors, it should give the most logical 'container' value (e.g. the mean)..

Comment: For my example above, let's say that the mean is 0. Then the error would be 5, and the squared error would be 25. However, if the model really has no idea if it should predict 5 instead of 20, perhaps the contribution to the loss function should be greater than 25. (I don't know how to do this, but I think iwbabn is after something like this.)

Comment: I think this is a bit problematic though, because for example the estimate of the mean / intercept in a standard model fundamentally depends on the loss being exactly that: the square of the error. I wonder how toying with the loss function based on confidence intervals would affect the integrity of the estimates.. Also difficult I suppose to make a confiidence (or unconfidence in this case) indicationi which requires coefficient estimates which then depend on an initial fixed loss function. I suppose it should be some iterative process then..?

Comment: It's routine to use loss functions other than MSE. That's not an issue. You're right that we're no longer doing OLS, but that's okay. There are lots of other ways to do regression.

Comment: Yes, but most 'unconfidence' indicators (just to give those predictions with high uncertainty a name) will rely on an existing model estimate, right? So there must be some iterative nature to it it seems to me..

Comment: @dave, I would second this answer. Penalised regression adds a cost term to coefficients, so that the predictions are shrunk 'towards the mean', if there is insufficient data. It has exactly the use case Op discusses. Note also that shrinking a coefficient to zero means you are using a slightly less complicated model, not that you literally shrink to the mean of your whole dataset. Eg if you have a feature hierarchy, ( eg products in a shop) regularisation will ensure you use the average at the level you have sufficient data.(but nothing stops you having multiple hierarchies and interactions)

Comment: I still think that this penalizes the parameters for having large standard errors rather than penalizing the predictions for lacking certainty. It seems that the OP is looking for the latter.

Comment: I am with Dave's interpretation. Here the model is assumed to be given. So for a trained say, ridge regression model, there still can be varying prediction intervals for different new inputs. So the same question applies.

Comment: I agree @iwbabn, the question is whether you want to penalise the model (and thus re-estimate) or the output. In the latter case, it really is subjective, I think, just like it is subjective whether a false positive or a false negative is 'worse'. Regarding your edit, it is imporant to note that if the model gives a 'wild' prediction - it is simply because that wild prediction is more likely given the data than the mean would be.. So in that sense it is slightly strange to propose the mean as (or any) alternative!